# In what movie is an AI defeated by a virus written on a Gameboy?

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, sy-fy

I'm looking for a movie where, near the end, the main character destroys an AI that was trying to take over with a computer virus he wrote on a Gameboy. He then nearly dies from Halogen gas that the AI was pumping into the room.

Other scenes include the AI messing with traffic lights, causing planes to collide, killing its creator, and a scene where it says "Kill [main character]" over and over through his computer.

It was a low budget movie on the Sci-Fi channel many years ago (maybe 10).

Answer (score 6):

The movie is [Terminal Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_Error), released in 2002.

From Wikipedia:

> Elliot, an ex-employee of a computer firm wants revenge and befriends the boss Brad's son Dylan giving him an MP3 file containing a computer virus. This virus creates havoc all across the city by poisoning the water with chlorine, making planes crash and ultimately developing an intelligence of its own. The virus is eventually traced to a server and is terminated by another equally powerful virus created by Brad and Dylan with a Game Boy Color.

Comment: Thank goodness it was a Gameboy Color, at least that way there’s a possibly they had syntax highlighting.